# Blazor Server Side - Location of js file references in _Host.cshtml

Tags: javascript, blazor

I have animations that I am trying to use but my problem is that they do not work if I have the references they way I thought I should have them. I can get them to work but then the Counter page, included in the default Blazor project does not work - the Counter is not counting which indicates that there is something seriously wrong and I will have other problems too. The animation JavaScript is in a file called bs-init.js.

Scenario one:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bs-init.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <app>
        <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    </app>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem: Animation works but the Counter does not.

Scenario two:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <app>
        <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    </app>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bs-init.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem: Counter works but the animation does not.

The content of my bs-init.js file is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-bs-hover-animate]')
        .mouseenter( function(){ var elem = $(this); elem.addClass('animated ' + elem.attr('data-bs-hover-animate')) })
        .mouseleave( function(){ var elem = $(this); elem.removeClass('animated ' + elem.attr('data-bs-hover-animate')) });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all script has to be grouped together.
I never put `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` anywhere but the body.
Try leaving it there. Even if it would work inside the head, it would stop your application from rendering till it is loaded.

For your other libraries; you can try putting them in the head. When you look at the developers tools (F12) - console tab, you will probably see error messages that things are broken because the library called is unknown.

Comment: As soon as I move any library, other than bs-int.js to the body, the animation stops working.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting in your console?

Comment: No error message in the console. It just looks like as soon as I move the scripts to the body, I no longer have event listeners for mouse over/out

Comment: I found the solution that can be seen in my answer here.

Comment: Moving blazor.server.js from Header to Body fixed it for me.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

This issue has the following solution:

Put the script references in the body. What seems to be really important here is to have the "_framework/blazor.server.js" reference in the body.

Wrap the content of the jquery code in a function like this:

```
function renderjQueryComponents() {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data-bs-hover-animate]')
        .mouseenter(function () { var elem = $(this); elem.addClass('animated ' + elem.attr('data-bs-hover-animate')) })
        .mouseleave(function () { var elem = $(this); elem.removeClass('animated ' + elem.attr('data-bs-hover-animate')) });
});

$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

}

In the Blazor component where the script is being used, inject the JS runtime:

```
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime
```

Override OnAfterRender:

```
protected override async void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("renderjQueryComponents");
    base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
}
```

And that's it - problem solved!